# How to add a div tag in iframe head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i just want to ask, how to add a div tag in iframe head. when I open the developer toolbar > elements in google chrome, i cant see mydiv tag in body. Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="callMe()">
        <div id="mydiv">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>hi</td>
                    <td>hello</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="test">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javscsript">
            (function callMe() { 
                var frame = $('iframe'),
                    contents = frame.contents(),
                    body = contents.find('body'),
                    styleTag = body.append('#mydiv');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included reference to the jQuery library?

Comment: Look at the console in your browser. You got a few problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` doesn't take a string selector, it needs a DOM element or jQuery object. Try this:

```
var frame = $('iframe'),
    contents = frame.contents(),
    body = contents.find('body'),
    styleTag = body.append($('#mydiv'));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2TY8/)

One thing worth noting is that `append()` returns the originally selected element, so in your code both the `body` and `styleTag` variables will contain the same element (the `body` of the `iframe`).